# Induction proof on substrings of a string

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Define S(n) as the smallest natural number containing exactly n substrings in its decimal representation which are prime numbers.

Prove that S(n) is defined for each n in N. i.e. for each n in N, there
exists a smallest natural number containing exactly n prime substrings.

I am really confused and lost on how to approach this, this has to be done using induction. I wrote the first 6 examples to gain some intuition or see a pattern but it didn't help.

S(0) = ''

S(1) = '2'

S(2) = '13'

S(3) = '23'

S(4) = '113', S(5) = '137', S(6) = '373'

Assuming S(k) is true and there are k substrings containing prime numbers then if i somehow use this to show k + 1, then i would be done but i don't know how i would go about it? Using strong induction didn't help either.

Any hints to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think appending $2$ at the end of the string will do the thing.

Comment: The question asks to prove the existence of the smallest natural number containing n prime sub-strings tho :/

Comment: Once you prove the existence, by well ordering principle, there should be such thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this solution if possible?

Comment: @Johm If you add a $2$ to the end, this certainly adds at least one prime substring. (the new $2$). But since there are no primes ending in $2$ other than $2$, this in fact adds precisely one new prime substring, so there is some number with exactly $n + 1$ prime substrings. Then it follows that there must be a least such number, which is the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)

Answer (score 4):

To prove the existence of $S(n)$, firstly note that $\underbrace{22\cdots\cdots2}_{n \text{ times}}$ has exactly $n$ prime substrings. Then the set
$$S_n = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \mid \text{$m$ has exactly $n$ prime substrings}\}$$
is not empty for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By well ordering principle, stating that every nonempty set of natural numbers contains the least element, $\min S_n$ exists, which is the value you are finding i.e. $S(n) = \min S_n$.